# how unique is my random number

Tags: probability, permutations

We use a random number generator to create numbers in the format of {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}. where the X represents a digit which is base 16 (hexadecimal). that's 0-9,A-F

The hexadecimal digits are grouped in a format that is 36 characters long -- 32 hexadecimal characters grouped as 8-4-4-4-12 and separated by four hyphens: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.

So right now the permutations of the number are 16^32 (thanks @henry) - right?

We generated 2000 of these numbers.

What I want do is just take the last 12 digits from each number and I need them to be unique. (the last part after the hyphen)

what's the probability that there would be collisions (or repeats) between those 2000 numbers?

Comment: Your 32^16 should be $16^{32}$.  Your question is about the probability of a collision with $2000$ samples from a uniform distribution over $16^{12}$ numbers, and this will be very small - possibly (not checked) about $7 \times 10^{-9}$

Comment: Relevant: [universally unique identifiers on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $N=16^{12}$ possibilities for the last number. Conversely, each number has a probability $p=\frac 1N = 16^{-12}$ of being picked. Let $P_n$ denote the probability that there are no collisions between $n$ numbers sampled this way.

Imagine generating the $2000$ samples sequentially:

- Having picked the first number, the probability of a collision of the $2$rd number with the first one is $p$. Thus, $P_2=1-p$.
- Having picked the first two numbers without a collision, the probability of a collision of the $3$rd number with the first $2$ numbers is $2p$. Thus, $P_3=P_2(1-2p)=(1-p)(1-2p)$.
- Having picked the first $i$ numbers without a collision, the probability of a collision of the $i+1$ number with the first $i$ numbers is $ip$. Thus, $P_{i+1}=(1-ip)P_i=\prod_{j=1}^i (1-jp)$.

Thus, the probability of having some repeats in $2000$ samples is given by $1-P_{2000}$, i.e. $$1-\prod_{j=1}^{1999} (1-jp)$$

(Edit: See comments to my answer for an approximation to this expression.)

Also, see [Collisions in a sample of uniform distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31823/collisions-in-a-sample-of-uniform-distribution).

Comment: I think this answer is correct but if $p\ll 1$ that product will turn out to be $\approx pn(n-1)/2$ approximately and it will be easier to calculate without multiplying lots of tiny fractions.

Comment: Because $(1-p)(1-2p)(1-3p)...(1-np)=(1-(1+2+3+....)p+O(p^2)\approx 1-pn(n-1)/2$

Comment: Should it not be $N=16^{12}$?

Comment: @A.M. You are right, I corrected my answer.