# What is the chance of collision of latter group of card number among different people?

Tags: probability-theory

Let's assume we are a payment system issuing 16-digit cards.
If we have X customers and issue Y cards, how to calculate the chance of at least single collision of last 4 digits within a single customer, assuming (for convenience of calculation) that:

- the last digit probability is random as well (10% probability of any digit). it is actually not that plain, since it is a Luhn checksum
- our customers order an equal amount of cards. Particularly, every customer gets ~`Y / X` cards

Now, we have X = 10000 customers.
We produce Y = 30000 cards to our customers.
The chance that two random cards within a payment system have a collision is always 1 / 10000.
Now, I am wondering about what is the chance that at least one customer will have two cards with the same four digits in the end of its numbers? How to calculate this probability and how to calculate the expected value of collisions?

It would be even better if someone also provides an answer without the given assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have overthought this. It is actually can be paraphrased as

> if every customer takes `N` random numbers from 0 to 9999, what is the chance of at least one duplicate". The total number of issued cards and other customers does not affect the probability of collision.

It is related to [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and solution is described in the following Math SE question:   [Probability of Random number repeating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11818/probability-of-random-number-repeating)

Particularly, if a customer issues 10 cards, then collision chance is 0.044913%.
If customer issue 2 cards each, the chance of collision is 0.01%, which means that every 10000-th customer will have a collision, which should have been obvious and expectable since the begining :)